# XSLT: set classes based on element descendants

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

I'm working with an XSL transformation on the following HTML:

```
<div id="context">
    <p>Sometimes, there is content here.</p>
</div>

<div id="main-content">
    <p>There is always content here.</p>
</div>

<div id="related">
    <img src="CMS PREVIEW ICON - ADMIN ONLY"/>
    <p>Sometimes, there is content here.</p>
    <p>The image is always the first child only if the user is inside the CMS, but it should be ignored if there is not other content present.</p>
</div>
```

Currently, I'm trying to adjust the class attribute on the `main-content` div and the `related` div, based on whether the `related` one has any descendants (that are not the CMS icon). Here's what I have:

```
<xsl:template match="div[@id='main-content']">
    <xsl:copy>
        <!-- copy the current body node contents -->
        <xsl:attribute name="class">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="//div[@id='related']/descendant::* and name(//div[@id='related']/*[1]) != 'img' or count(//div[@id='related']/descendant::* > 1)  and name(//div[@id='related']/*[1]) != 'img'">span6</xsl:when>
                <!-- left nav but no right col -->
                <xsl:when test="not(//div[@id='related']/descendant::*) or (count(//div[@id='related']/descendant::* = 1) and name(//div[@id='related']/*[1]) = 'img')">span9</xsl:when>                    
                <!-- no left nav and populated right col -->
                <xsl:when test="//div[@id='related']/descendant::* and  (count(//div[@id='related']/descendant::* = 1) and name(//div[@id='related']/*[1]) != 'img') and not( //div[@class='data-entry wide'])">span9</xsl:when>                    
                <xsl:otherwise>span12</xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        <!-- output the rest -->
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="div[@id='related']">
    <xsl:copy>
        <!-- copy the current body node contents -->
        <xsl:attribute name="class">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="count(* = 0) or (count(* = 1) and name(*[1]) = 'img')">hidden</xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="descendant::*">span3</xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>hidden</xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        <!-- output the rest -->
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

And then, if `related` is given a class of hidden, I remove it later so that it doesn't take up bandwidth, DOM space, etc.

I thought this would work correctly as it does seem to get the right values in the xpath, but it just doesn't remove the elements like it should. It's a bit weird, since I need to know:

1. Are there any descendants in `related` for the views that are not inside the CMS
2. AND, for the views inside the CMS, are there descendants that are not the specific image (other images would always be wrapped in a div, link, etc.)

Any thoughts?

Thanks,
Jonathan

Comment: For one thing, `count(* = 0)` is not valid XPath. `count(*) = 0` would be the valid way to do it, but you'd be better off using `not(*)`. Similarly for `count(* = 1)` you could use `not(*[2])`. I'm having some trouble deciphering your first set of `<xsl:when>`s. Could you break them down for us?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if I'm not completely sure if I have the right understanding  of your request, I'll give it a try.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

        <xsl:template match="div[@id='main-content']">
    <xsl:copy>
        <!-- copy the current body node contents -->
        <xsl:attribute name="class">
            <xsl:choose>
                <!-- "related" has any descendants (that are not the CMS icon). -->
                <xsl:when test="//div[@id='related']/* and 
                          count(//div[@id='related']/img)  !=  count(//div[@id='related']/*) ">span6</xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>span9</xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        <!-- output the rest -->
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="div[@id='related']">
    <xsl:copy>
        <!-- copy the current body node contents -->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        <xsl:choose>
                <!-- it should be ignored if there is not other content present -->
                <xsl:when test=" count(img) = count(*)">
                    <xsl:attribute name="class">hidden</xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:attribute name="class">span3</xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>

                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        <!-- output the rest -->
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates  select="node() | @*" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```